# OpenNMS Email Notification not working

Tags: opennms

I have installed OpenNMS Horizon and configured notifcations as follows:

1. users admin and rtc have an email address;
2. both are part of the Email-Admin group (Admin / Configure Notifications Destination Paths);
3. notifications have been turned on (Admin / Event Management);
4. for testing purposes, I have configured a custom nodeDown event, which has the Email-Admin group on its destination path (My Node DOWN Alert; OpenNMS-defined node event: nodeDown; uei.opennms.org/nodes/nodeDown)

   **Current Rule:**

   ```
   (IPADDR != '0.0.0.0')
   ```
5. I have set up a gmail account in xxx as follows:

   org.opennms.core.utils.useJMTA=false

   org.opennms.core.utils.transport=smtps

   org.opennms.core.utils.mailHost=smtp.gmail.com

   org.opennms.core.utils.smtpport=587

   org.opennms.core.utils.smtpssl.enable=true

   org.opennms.core.utils.authenticate=true

   org.opennms.core.utils.authenticateUser=XXX@gmail.com

   org.opennms.core.utils.authenticatePassword=XXX

   org.opennms.core.utils.starttls.enable=true

   org.opennms.core.utils.messageContentType=text/html

   org.opennms.core.utils.charset=us-ascii

   org.opennms.core.utils.fromAddress=OpenNMS Administrator
6. Gmail is configured with setting *allow less secure applications*.

**My Question:**

When I am powering off my test machine, I can see a *nodeDown* event in the Horizon Dashboard. However, the system does not send an email notification.

According to notefid.log (/opt/opennms/logs/notifd.log) the system does not even try to send an email.

Changing the port to org.opennms.core.utils.smtpport=465 is not working either.

What am I missing? Please advise!

**EDIT**

1. Email is working properly with this configuration (/opt/opennms/etc/javamail-configuration.properties):

   ```
   org.opennms.core.utils.useJMTA=false
   org.opennms.core.utils.transport=smtps
   org.opennms.core.utils.mailHost=smtp.gmail.com
   org.opennms.core.utils.smtpport=465    
   org.opennms.core.utils.smtpssl.enable=true
   org.opennms.core.utils.authenticate=true
   org.opennms.core.utils.authenticateUser=xxx@gmail.com
   org.opennms.core.utils.authenticatePassword=xxx
   org.opennms.core.utils.starttls.enable=true
   org.opennms.core.utils.messageContentType=text/html
   org.opennms.core.utils.charset=us-ascii
   org.opennms.core.utils.fromAddress=OpenNMS Administrator <xxx@gmail.com>
   ```
2. A scheduled outage prevented the system from sending emails. The scheduled outage did not vanish upon deletion. I had to add a second outage and then delete the first entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of reasons why e-mails can't be sent. In Step 4 you state that you have configured a custom nodeDown event (which I assume is different than the default nodeDown event). Verify that your custom notice is also enabled.

Your next step will be to edit `/opt/opennms/etc/log4j2.xml` and scroll to the bottom. Set the log level for "notifd" to DEBUG. Then repeat your test and my guess is you will see an error in the log with connecting to GMail. Correct that and you should be good to go.